# FabricJS - clip image to shape with background image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I would like to make a loaded image will be clipped by created shape. Here is result of my work. 
https://jsfiddle.net/qqv32b5z/1/

It works well if you add an image. The loaded image is clipped by the existing shape.

The problem starts when I will add a background image.
The globalCompositeOperation with parameter source-atop, are not pointing to the shape, but to the background image.

How can I achieve a result that image will be clipped by the shape, even if background image is loaded?

Here is a version which not works as expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/undss329/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    'selection': false
});
let center = canvas.getCenter();

let currentShape = new fabric.Path('M0,0H63.73L98.64,47H34.91Z', {
    fill: '#333333',
    opacity: 1,
    hasBorders: true,
    hasControls: true,
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
    selectable: true,
    preserveObjectStacking: true,
    objectCaching: false,
    top: center.top,
    left: center.left,
});

canvas.setActiveObject(currentShape);
canvas.add(currentShape);
canvas.renderAll();


canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg',
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        top: center.top,
        left: center.left,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
    });

document.getElementById('image').onchange = function (e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            var image = new fabric.Image(img, {
                objectCaching: false,
                hasControls: true,
                selectable: true
            });
            image.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            image.scaleToWidth(currentShape.width);
            image.top = center.top;
            image.left = center.left;
            canvas.add(image);
            canvas.renderAll();
            canvas.setActiveObject(image);
            image.setCoords();
        };
        img.src = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
};
```